# Merge specific lines - awk/sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file with several thousand numbers arranged like this:

```
line 1: #0 #1 #2 #3 #4 #5
line 2: #6 #7 #8 #9 #10 #11
...
line 111: #106 #107 #108 #109 #110
line 112: #111 #112 #113 #114 #115
...
```

What I would like to do is format my file to look like this:

```
line 1: #0 #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #111 #112 #113 #114 #115 ...
line 2: #6 #7 #8 #9 #10 #11 #116 #117 #118 #119 #120 #121 ...
...
line 111: #106 #107 #108 #109 #110 #218 #219 #220 #221 #222 #223...
```

basically I want to arrange my numbers in a 111x111 matrix (so after the first 111 lines which would stay in place line 112 would be merged with the first line, line 113 with the second etc and this would happen for every 111 lines). Is there any way of doing this with awk/sed?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with having temporary files, you can use `split` then `paste`. `split` splits a file into smaller files of `n` lines each, and `paste` takes input files and concatenates them vertically.

Choosing an arbitrary prefix `tmp` for our temporary files:

```
split -l 111 input.txt tmp
paste tmp* >output.txt
rm tmp*
```

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly, I don't mind having temp files!

Comment: No problem. Feel free to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, untested since you didn't provide testable sample input/output:

```
awk -v RS='\\s' '{ORS=(NR%111?"\n":OFS)}1' file
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and `\s`.